# where is the user content on a Mac OS X disk?

Tags: filesystems, osx, hard-disk, hfs+

I have a friend's Mac OS X disk that comes with an `HFS+` partition. I am supposed to recover the personal data from this disk (it's not yet clear if the FS is corrupted or the disk dying), but for the life of me I cannot understand what is the traditional file-tree structure on a `Mac OS X` disk.

Where is the user content located? On Windows it's in `My Documents`, on Linux it's in `/home/user`, but where is it on `Mac OS X`?

---

**EDIT1**: If I mount the drive on Linux I get the following:

```
liv@liv-HP-Compaq-dc7900:/media/Macintosh HD$ cat /etc/mtab | grep -i hfsplus
/dev/sdc2 /media/Macintosh\040HD hfsplus ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks 0 0
```

And doing an `ls` on the mount point doesn't contain any mention of `Users` in it:

```
liv@liv-HP-Compaq-dc7900:/media/Macintosh HD$ ls -lh
ls: cannot access home: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libpeerconnection.log: Input/output error
ls: cannot access net: Input/output error
ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
total 20M
drwxrwxr-x 1 root   80  53 Oct 18 22:07 Applications
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  39 Sep 26 00:51 bin
drwxrwxr-t 1 root   80   2 Jul  9  2009 cores
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root   2 Jul  9  2009 dev
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11 Sep 24  2009 etc -> private/etc
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root   80  60 Mar 20  2010 Guides de l’utilisateur et informations -> /Library/Documentation/User Guides and Information.localized
d????????? ? ?    ?      ?            ? home
-????????? ? ?    ?      ?            ? libpeerconnection.log
drwxrwxr-t 1 root   80  58 Mar 27  2013 Library
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root   4 Sep 18  2012 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20M Jun  8  2011 mach_kernel
d????????? ? ?    ?      ?            ? net
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2 Jul  9  2009 Network
drwxr-xr-x 1  501   80   3 Oct 26  2010 opt
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6 Sep 24  2009 private
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  67 Sep 26 00:52 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4 Jul  3  2011 System
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11 Sep 24  2009 tmp -> private/tmp
```

But I do see a `home`, though. Does this imply some weird `Mac OS X` configuration? Or is it likely that `Users` was deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users' home directories can be found in in `/Users/`.

Comment: Well, that's what [this guide](http://jclark.org/weblog/2005/05/24/ubuntumount/) suggested, too, but I couldn't see any `/Users` in the file structure. There is a `/home` dir, though.